# Seed Object with Shadow Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, seed

I'm trying to seed an object that uses shadow properties using Entity Framework core 3.1 but when I try to create a migration I get:

`The seed entity for entity type 'MyObject' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Created'.`

The property "Created" is a shadow property added in OnModelCreating so I don't have access to it in the model configuration. The Microsoft article [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) says, "If the entity type has any properties in shadow state an anonymous class can be used to provide the values...." I tried that as well and got the same error.

Here is my configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    // Tried this before and after the shadow properties, same error
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration( new MyObjectConfiguration() );

    // Tried to seed here too instead of in the MyObjectConfiguration
    //modelBuilder.Entity<Brokerage>().HasData( new
                            //{
                                //Id = 1,
                                //Name = "A Really Cool Object",
                                //PhoneNumber = "1234567891"
                            //} );

    // Create shadow properties
    foreach ( var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
          .Where( e => typeof( IAuditable ).IsAssignableFrom( e.ClrType ) ) )
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity( entityType.ClrType )
            .Property<DateTime>( "Created" );

        modelBuilder.Entity( entityType.ClrType )
            .Property<DateTime>( "Modified" );

        modelBuilder.Entity( entityType.ClrType )
            .Property<string>( "CreatedBy" );

        modelBuilder.Entity( entityType.ClrType )
            .Property<string>( "ModifiedBy" );
    }

    base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );
}


public class BrokerageConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyObject>
{
    public void Configure( EntityTypeBuilder<MyObject> builder )
    {
        ...

        //builder.Entity<MyObject>()
        //    .HasData( new { Id = 1, Name = "A Really Cool Object", PhoneNumber = "1234567891" } );

        builder.HasData
        (
            new MyObject
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "A Really Cool Object",
                PhoneNumber = "1234567891"
            }
        );
    }
}
```

How do I seed data that uses shadow properties?

Comment: Anonymous type is exactly what you are supposed to use. *"I tried that as well and got the same error"* - I don't see you specifying shadow property values in your anonymous type example.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, that's what I was missing. I hate when I overlook the obvious. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness (as I was looking for a solution myself), using an anon class would be the solution as commented above:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Brokerage>().HasData(new
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "A Really Cool Object",
    PhoneNumber = "1234567891",
    CreatedBy = "sysdba",
    Created = DateTime.Now,
    ModifiedBy = "sysdba",
    Modified = DateTime.Now
});
```